# How to manage position in recycler view when scroll after notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Here is my code, I have to call method `getServerResponse()` for first time to get store in `arraylist` and when I scrolls down I have to call method `getServerResponseScroll()`. I got result and notify adapter but after scrolling down and up data changes position or may be not visible or get changed. I had created custom adapter for chat. Please help me how to sort out this kind of problem.

```
public class ChatDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String macAddress;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Activity context;
ChatAdapter adapter;
EditText etText;
DatabaseAdapter db;
NetClient nc;
EditText edtSend;
Button btnSend;
DataPref mDataPref;
static int page = 0;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
JSONArray chatDetailListJsonArray;
String toId, channelId, toProfilePic, deviceToken, deviceOsType;
static ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatDetailModels = new ArrayList<ChatDetailModel>();

//    User mchatUSer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_detail);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    edtSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSend);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    db = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDataPref = DataPref.getInstance(this);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
    etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
    toId = getIntent().getStringExtra("toId");
    channelId = getIntent().getStringExtra("channelId");
    toProfilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra("toProfilePic");
    deviceToken = getIntent().getStringExtra("deviceToken");
    deviceOsType = getIntent().getStringExtra("deviceOsType");

    getServerResponse(this);

    connectionForSend();

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}
void getServerResponse(final Context context){
    StringRequest strReqNewsList = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.getChatDetailListUrl, new
            Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("GetNewsList Response POST " + response);

             /*
                   if (progressDialog != null) {
                       if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                           progressDialog.dismiss();
                   }*/
                    String message = "";
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        String responseStatus = jsonObjectResponse.getString("status");
                        message = jsonObjectResponse.getString("message");
                        if (responseStatus.equals("true")) {
                             chatDetailListJsonArray = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONArray("data");
                            if(page==0) {
                                GetChat.getInstance(context).deleteAllTableData("tbl_chat_detail", channelId);
                            }
                            //  JSONObject chatListJsonObject=  new JSONObject(gson.toJson(chatListJsonArray));
                            ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatlistModels = new Gson()
                                    .fromJson(chatDetailListJsonArray.toString(),
                                            new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
                                            }.getType());

                            for (int i = 0; i < chatDetailListJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                ChatDetailModel chatlistModel = chatlistModels.get(i);
                                chatlistModel.setChannel_id(channelId);
                                GetChat.getInstance(context).addChatDetailList(new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(chatlistModel)));
                            }
                            JSONArray chatListJsonArray = GetChat.getInstance(ChatDetailActivity.this).getChatDetailListJsonArray(channelId);
                            chatDetailModels = new Gson().fromJson(chatListJsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
                            }.getType());
                            implemantation();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JSONArray chatListJsonArray = GetChat.getInstance(ChatDetailActivity.this).getChatDetailListJsonArray(channelId);
                        chatDetailModels = new Gson().fromJson(chatListJsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        implemantation();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         /*  if (progressDialog != null) {
               if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
           }*/
            error.printStackTrace();
            JSONArray chatListJsonArray = GetChat.getInstance(ChatDetailActivity.this).getChatDetailListJsonArray(channelId);
            chatDetailModels = new Gson().fromJson(chatListJsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
            }.getType());
            implemantation();
            //  DatabaseAdapter.deleteDatabase(context);
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("to_id", toId);
            params.put("from_id", mDataPref.getUserId());
            params.put("page",page+"");
            params.put("last_sync_date_time", "");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };

    strReqNewsList.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(40 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
    AppController.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(strReqNewsList);
}

void getServerResponseScroll(final Context context) {
    StringRequest strReqNewsList = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.getChatDetailListUrl, new
            Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("GetNewsList Response POST " + response);

                    String message = "";
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        String responseStatus = jsonObjectResponse.getString("status");
                        message = jsonObjectResponse.getString("message");
                        if (responseStatus.equals("true")) {
                            chatDetailListJsonArray = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONArray("data");

                            //  JSONObject chatListJsonObject=  new JSONObject(gson.toJson(chatListJsonArray));
                            ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatlistModels = new Gson()
                                    .fromJson(chatDetailListJsonArray.toString(),
                                            new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
                                            }.getType());

                            for (int i = 0; i < chatDetailListJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                ChatDetailModel chatlistModel = chatlistModels.get(i);
                                chatlistModel.setChannel_id(channelId);
                                GetChat.getInstance(context).addChatDetailList(new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(chatlistModel)));
                            }
                            JSONArray chatListJsonArray = GetChat.getInstance(ChatDetailActivity.this).getChatDetailListJsonArray(channelId);
                            //  chatDetailModels.clear();
                            ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatDetailModels1 = new ArrayList<ChatDetailModel>();
                            chatDetailModels1 = new Gson().fromJson(chatListJsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ChatDetailModel>>() {
                            }.getType());
                            chatDetailModels.clear();
                            chatDetailModels.addAll(chatDetailModels1);
                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         /*  if (progressDialog != null) {
               if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
           }*/
            error.printStackTrace();

            //  DatabaseAdapter.deleteDatabase(context);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("to_id", toId);
            params.put("from_id", mDataPref.getUserId());
            params.put("page", page + "");
            params.put("last_sync_date_time", "");

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };

    strReqNewsList.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(40 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
    AppController.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(strReqNewsList);
}

void implemantation() {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    adapter = new ChatAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), chatDetailModels);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(chatDetailModels.size() - 1);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ChatDetailActivity.this, ProfilesDetailActivity.class);
            //   i.putExtra("profileId",ChatlistModel.get(position).getId());
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            page++;
            getServerResponseScroll(ChatDetailActivity.this);


        }
    });
}


// Adapter for chat
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatDetailModels;
    private Context context;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChatDetailModel> chatDetailModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.chatDetailModels = chatDetailModels;

    }

    @Override
    public ChatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_lsit_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (chatDetailModels.get(position).getFrom_username().equalsIgnoreCase(mDataPref.getUsername())) {
            viewHolder.messageTextRight.setText(chatDetailModels.get(position).getMessage());
            viewHolder.chatLeftLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (mDataPref.getProfilePicFullUrl().equals("null") || mDataPref.getProfilePicFullUrl().equals("")) {
                viewHolder.fromImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_profile_pic);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(context).load(mDataPref.getProfilePicFullUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_pic).transform(new CircleTransform()).resize(40, 40).into(viewHolder.fromImageView);

            }
        } else {
            viewHolder.messageTextLeft.setText(chatDetailModels.get(position).getMessage());
            viewHolder.chatRightLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (toProfilePic.equals("null") || toProfilePic.equals("")) {
                viewHolder.toImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_profile_pic);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(context).load(toProfilePic).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_pic).transform(new CircleTransform()).resize(40, 40).into(viewHolder.toImageView);

            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatDetailModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout chatLeftLayout;
        private ImageView toImageView;
        private TextView messageTextLeft;
        private LinearLayout chatRightLayout;
        private TextView messageTextRight;
        private ImageView fromImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            chatLeftLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chatLeftLayout);
            toImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.toImageView);
            messageTextLeft = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_left);
            chatRightLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chatRightLayout);
            messageTextRight = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_right);
            fromImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromImageView);

        }
    }
 }


}
```

Comment: make your position final .

Comment: why do you clear `chatDetailModels.clear();`  in `getServerResponseScroll`

Comment: actually I am inserting again all record in proper sequence @Shubhank

Comment: can you make a basic sample of how this is going on ? Currently its quite unclear what position change and what output you are getting vs the expected

Comment: Solved I have forget Visible other layout after set visibility gone on adapter Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

From onSaveInstanceState documentation:

```
Called when the LayoutManager should save its state. This is a good time to save your
             * scroll position, configuration and anything else that may be required to restore the same
             * layout state if the LayoutManager is recreated.
             * RecyclerView does NOT verify if the LayoutManager has changed between state save and
             * restore. This will let you share information between your LayoutManagers but it is also
             * your responsibility to make sure they use the same parcelable class.
```

To get current state of recyclerview:

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
```

to restore saved instance:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```

Comment: I am new in android and I don't know how can I use this.